# WCF Transactions without MSDTC

Tags: wcf, transactions, transactionscope

I need to coordinate a transaction between several SOAP services implemented in WCF. I know I can use the WS-Atomic transaction or oleTransactions.

For some technical reasons, I cannot make any use of the MSDTC. Is there a way I can coordinate a transaction between services without using the MSDTC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't we make WCF to manage transactions without implicitly using MSDTC.

i.e. The wcf application should manage transactions even when I disable the Distributed Transaction Co-ordinator.

Isn't is possible.

**You need to visit this link:**

[Configure MS DTC Component Services for WCF Transactions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uGjGgDKw-MyJR_RRnJ_Qabtl9CcHby41iweeE4JX3kQ/edit)